# AngularJS disabled select input behaviour not same as native HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

It seems that when an input or select is disabled in angularjs, the model value remains the same. My problem is that this is not the same as native form behaviour in HTML, and that I have to invoke some extra behaviour via an `ng-change` scope method in order to get the proper behaviour, which is for the value to be set to null if the input or select input is disabled. 
Here is my example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <select ng-disabled="disableIt" ng-model="data">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="textData" ng-disabled="disableIt" />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disableIt"/>
    <br />
    Select Data: {{selectData}}
    <br/>
    Text Data: {{textData}}
</div>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.selectData = 1;
    $rootScope.textData = "test";
});
</script>
```

You can test it out on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9wbtnhno/1/

The desired result is for the `textData` and `selectData` models to be null when disabled.

Comment: You need to modify your code.. It is not proper.

Comment: Any more info to give on that? That's why this question is here after all...

Comment: CAn I do it in My way..?

Comment: @Ved be my guest. I've only provided a basic example - it's not how I would code it normally. I would hope people would overlook that! (TAMTOWTDI)